# VBA print dialog function is printing out a blank page when it should not

Tags: excel, vba, printing

Below is my VBA code to print out a label text file. The Notepad.exe display the correct values I need to print but when the print dialog pops up, I choose a printer, it prints out a blank page. Any clues/reasoning why?!?!??!

`Public Sub PrintLabelTextFile2(Optional strPathAndFilename As String)

```
If strPathAndFilename = "" Then strPathAndFilename = LabelTextFile

Dim hwnd As Long
hwnd = Application.hwnd

Dim printerName As String
printerName = ""

Dim dialogTitle As String
dialogTitle = "Select Printer"

Dim filter As String
filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt"

X = Shell("Notepad.exe " & strPathAndFilename, vbNormalFocus)

MsgBox ("Please select a printer from the print dialog, then print the file. " & _
    "Once the printer dialog is closed, the file will be deleted!")

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")

Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show , , , , , , , , , , , 1

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")

Kill (strPathAndFilename)
```

End Sub`

I have tried chat gpting it for hours now and it cannot give me a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

here is the macro you need, I hope it works for you and is what you need.

```html
Sub PrintAndDeleteTextFile()
    Dim strPathAndFilename As String
    Dim LabelTextFile As String
    Dim hwnd As Long
    Dim printerName As String
    Dim dialogTitle As String
    Dim filter As String
    Dim X As Variant

    ' Text file path and file name
    LabelTextFile = "C:\path\to\your\textfile.txt"

    ' Path and file name to be printed
    strPathAndFilename = LabelTextFile

    hwnd = Application.hwnd
    printerName = ""
    dialogTitle = "Select Printer"
    filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt"

    X = Shell("cmd /c notepad /p """ & strPathAndFilename & """", vbNormalFocus)

    MsgBox "Please select a printer from the print dialog, then print the file. Once the printer dialog is closed, the file will be deleted!"

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")

    ' Delete the following line to avoid the printer selection dialog box
    ' Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")

    Kill strPathAndFilename
End Sub
```